# My marigold is dying. Please help

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, transplanting

[image]

So I’ve had this Marigold for a few months so far, and now it seems to be dying. Can I still save it? Shall I replant it? or cut the flowers ?

Any advice could help. I live in Costa Rica central valley, can be sunny half a day and the other half raining. I keep my marigold on the balcony, it gets a few hours of sun, and the rain doesn’t get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plant looks like Tagetes patula, common name French marigold, and I'm sorry to say that they only last a year, or one growing season, because they are annuals. That  means they grow from seed into plants, start flowering, continue flowering for some months, and then just die. In colder regions, they die as soon as the first frost arrives, but even in zones without frost, they will die anyway. There are one or two perennial marigolds - Tagetes lucida (common name Mexican/Spanish tarragon) and Tagetes palmeri (Mountain marigold) if you want a plant that lives longer. Tagetes lucida is similar in appearance, but usually has single flowers. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/marigolds-perennials-annuals-63218.html

Comment: thank you so much, I didn’t know that.. that’s too sad, but thank you for the information, I will try to look for the other ones as well!